# facebook application access user profile id, username, profile photo

Tags: facebook

i'm writing something like forum for my fans page, i want to use user's profile username & photo of each message post by user. i'm finding a way to access user's profile name & photo.

Anyone knows how to do it? thanks

Comment: Much too vague - please add more details. What language? How far have you got? Have you seen the Facebook documentation?

Comment: thanks, i'm using php, i've read documentation but no ideas

Answer (score -1):

The [Apps on Facebook.com](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/) page should tell you everything you need to know to get started.